# Gradient Colors changing unexpectedly

Tags: vba, excel, gradient, linear-gradients

I have been working on a formatting Macro that takes in selections and formats them according to chosen values in a userform.  One of these options creates a large merged cell with a color gradient from a light to dark red.

When I run the macro, the cells are all formatted appropriately, but when I navigate around the sheet, I've noticed a strange issue where the color of the gradient will change to blue instead of red colors.  Interestingly, the original color will randomly return, sometimes even giving a gradient from blue to red or red to blue.

If I use the format painter to pull the miscolored cell and test it elsewhere, the new broken/changing color scheme moves with it.  I've included the code that formats the merged Cell below.  Is there an issue, perhaps, with how I am designating the interior color?

```
With Range(WorkingRange(1, 2), WorkingRange(1, WorkingRange.Count - 1))
    .Merge
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .WrapText = True
    .Interior.Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).Color = 255
    .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).TintAndShade = 0
    .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color = 130
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `ColorStop` 0 two times. Second time with default color.

Should be

```
...
    .Interior.Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
     .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color = RGB(130, 0, 0)
...
```

Using the `RGB` function will make it more flexible for usage with different colors.

Comment: I think this might not even be a code issue.  I just closed and reopened the document after having changed the code you suggested and formatted a test area, and the colors changed from when I formatted it (going from white to dark red) to when I reopened the file (now going from desired red to blue).  Any ideas?

Comment: Tried to add image links but couldn't, so here they are: 

[After formatting](http://i.imgur.com/rwQcqvT.png)

[After reopening](http://i.imgur.com/8tLgT0m.png)

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce your problem using Excel 2007. It works as expected even after closing and reopening.